# Why is my query only updating odd numbered rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on code to simply update rows one at a time in a database table. However only odd numbered rows are being updated while even numbered rows are not being updated.

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php
require_once ("connect.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

$query = "UPDATE tbl_shows SET shows_title='$title', shows_description='$description' WHERE shows_id='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

 if ($result) {
    header ("Location: shows.php?=success");
    exit ();
} else {
    echo "<p>Still doesn't work</p>";
        exit ();
}
?>
```

I have printed my $id, $title, and $description variables and they all appear as they should.

How do I change my code so that both even and odd numbered rows will be updated.

Edit:

Echoing $id, $title, $description and $query show the same for both odd and even numbered rows.

What mysql_error() outputs:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near (part of the data from the row appears here and cuts off the error) WHE' at line 1

The query:

```
UPDATE tbl_shows SET shows_title='Title is here', shows_description='Description is here' WHERE shows_id='2'
```

Comment: **warning** your code has sql injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What happens if you echo $id and $query for your odd numbered queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're code has easy sql injection vulnerabilities**, which is probably causing the inadvertent error your seeing. For instance, if your $description looks like this:

```
Best movie ever!!! You're going to love it!
```

...then your concatenated query will look like this:

```
UPDATE tbl_shows SET shows_title='Title is here', shows_description='Best movie ever!!! You're going to love it!' WHERE shows_id='2'
```

**The problem with this, is the apostrophe in `you're` is going to cause the value for `show_description` to terminate**, and the rest of the query won't make sense anymore to SQL.

At the very least, **use mysql_real_escape_string()** to sanitize the variables you add to your query, and better yet, use php's PDO library

Answer (score 0):

It is not immediately obvious what may be causing the even items to not update from what you have posted. I suggest that you use the [mysql_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) function to display the exact error message you are getting when the $result is false. According to PHP docs, mysql_result only returns false on error so that's a good indication that something weird may be up.

Comment: I have used the mysql_error function and it says I have a syntax error, but it cuts off halfway so I cannot see exactly where.

Comment: @akiri Could you edit your original post with the query and corresponding error message you get? I think it would allow us to help you better. MySQL errors almost always have elipses after an error and only shows you the most relevant part of the query with the error.